# Exercise from Rosenthal: extending finitely additive to countably additive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

My question is about whether the following exercise can be proven with an argument that I give.

Here's the exercise: Let $\mathcal{J}$ be a semi-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Let $P: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $P(\Omega) = 1$, where $P$ satisfies $P( \bigcup_n D_n) = \sum_n P(D_n)$ for *finite* disjoint collections $\{ D_n \}$ (finite additivity). Suppose further that, whenever $A_1, A_2, ...$ are finite disjoint unions of elements of $\mathcal{J}$, such that $A_{n + 1} \subset A_n$, and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \emptyset$, we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = 0$. Prove that $P$ is also countably additive.

Here a "semi-algebra" of subsets of $\Omega$ is a collection that contains $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$, is closed under finite intersection, and the complement of any element of $\mathcal{J}$ is equal to a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal{J}$.

Attempt at a proof:

Following a hint, take a collection of disjoint sets $D_1, D_2, D_3, ... \in \mathcal{J}$ such that $\bigcup_n D_n \in \mathcal{J}$, and write $A_n = (\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty D_i) - (\bigcup_{j = 1}^k D_j) = \bigcup_{i = n+1} ^\infty D_i$. Note that $A_{n + 1} = \bigcup_{i = n + 2}^\infty D_i \subset \bigcup_{i = n + 1} ^ \infty D_i = A_n$, and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty (\bigcup_{i = n+1}^\infty D_i) = \emptyset$. Since $\mathcal{J}$ is a semi-algebra, each $A_n$ can be written as a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal{J}$. Therefore, by the hypothesis, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = 0$.

Let $n$ be arbitrary, and consider $E = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup \cdots \cup D_n$. Now, $E\cup A_n = \bigcup_{j = 1} ^\infty D_j$. Since $A_n$ could be written as a finite union of disjoint elements of $\mathcal{J}$, and $E$ is also a finite disjoint union, and $E$ and $A_n$ are disjoint, we can use finite additivity and write 
$$P(E\cup A_n) = P(E) + P(A_n),$$ which implies that

$$P(\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty D_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(D_i) + P(A_n)$$

by finite additivity. Passing to the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get that

$$P(\bigcup_{j = 1} ^\infty D_j ) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1} ^n P(D_i) + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n),$$ and thus

$$P(\bigcup_n^\infty D_n ) = \sum_n^\infty P(D_n).$$

I know you can't interchange limits and probability measures in general, but since I think the LHS of the main equation doesn't depend on $n$, then this logic is valid. But it relies on being able to write $P(E\cup A_n) = P(E) + P(A_n)$. I think you can do this by the logic I gave. I am learning how to write rigorous math, and so please point out any flaws in the above proof.